# Oracle - How to make auto-increment column with varchar type?

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment

In my assignment with Oracle 11g, I am asked to make a table with column has this structure:

```
    [NL|TE|][0-9]^10
```

Where NL or TE is inputed when INSERT row and [0-9]^10 is an auto-increment 10 digits number.
Example:

```
    NL1234567890 or TE0253627576
```

When INSERT, the user should only write this:

```
    INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ('NL');
```

And the DBMS take care of the rest. So how can I do so? Im still a newbie in this thing.

Comment: Look into table triggers

Comment: You could always use a sequence.

Comment: @paqogomez and Bracuz Just looked at TRIGGER and sequence, look like what I need, but how can I combine the two? Since the data has both the character and number. Can someone show me a example SQL code?

Comment: All these are good answers, but @Gary_W's combines both a trigger and a sequence to answer the question exactly as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_seq;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_tablename_BI
BEFORE INSERT
ON your_tablename
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :NEW.your_col := :NEW.your_col || trim(to_char(your_seq.nextval, '0000000000'));

END your_tablename_BI;
/
```

Comment: If you start your sequence at a high enough value, you don't have to concatenate the 0's.

Comment: This code could do it. But can you explain the "your_tablename_BU" at the end ? I didnt see it in the TRIGGER syntax.

Comment: @Tr1et Sorry I was not clear.  That is just the name of the trigger; the name of the table with "BI" for "before insert" (you could have other triggers too). Oops that was a typo as well, should have been "BI".  I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code?

```
'NL' || to_char(yoursequence.nextval)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep them as separate columns. One is a VARCHAR2 that takes `NL` or whatever, the other is a NUMBER which is populated by the sequence.

You can then concatenate them at query time (put it in a view if you want) or use a virtual column.

Why? I can almost guarantee you that at some point you'll have a requirement to query the table on the character portion, or the numeric portion, or to sort on one or the other. Since you kept them separate, this is easy. If you had squashed them into a single column, you would have had to parse the values out at query time which leads to more complicated code than you need.

Comment: While I agree, the way the question is phrased suggests that this is not an option.  It might be an academic exercise.

Comment: The OP's question doesn't suggest either of those things. He's "been asked" to build something that works. This solution will work exactly as needed - I've used this technique before.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thank you, I will keep this technique in mind, but Bracuk guessed right that it is a academic assignment, and I cant even change the column data type.